# CollectionView Cell Crash - Assertion failure

Tags: ios, swift

I got the following error when I reload the `UICollectionView` cell inside a Closure

> Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView
>   _endItemAnimationsWithInvalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:animator:],
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore/UIKit-3698.84.16/UICollectionView.m:6120
>   (lldb)

```
 DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
       self!.fillCellImage(pixbayUrl: self.pixabayPhotoArray[indexPath.row].webformatURL!, photoId: indexPath.row) { (image, id) in
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
              let indexPath = IndexPath(item: id, section: 0)

              if(self.photosArray[indexPath.row].isDownloadImage == true){

                  self.PixbayPhotoCollectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
               }else{
                   self.photosArray[id].isDownloadImage = image.isDownloadImage
                   self.photosArray[id].image = image.image
                   if self.PixbayPhotoCollectionView != nil {
                         self.PixbayPhotoCollectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
                    }
              }
                    }
           }
   }
```

I reload the `UICollectionView` when the Image is downloaded.Please suggest me to solve this issue

Comment: put the image async loading logic inside the collectionView cell, should work, if you want to update some status in the Viewcontroller use a closure in the cell and notify the viewController

Comment: refer Kingfisher library. It has great doc. and easy to implement.